# Paypal TLS 1.2 settings for Magento

Tags: magento-1.9, paypal

I received an e-mail from paypal regarding their TLS 1.2 upgrade.

They have an extended page on what to do over here: https://www.paypal.com/us/webapps/mpp/tls-http-upgrade

As mentioned in this document you can do some checks if you have to do some changes. Which I did:

1. Are you hosted? - Answer: Yes
2. Does your system support TLS 1.2 and HTTP/1.1. I contacted my hosting about this and they upgraded the system to the latest Curl version. And they said now my system will now support TLS 1.2 and HTTP/1.1
3. Have tou hard coded an earlier version of TLS and HTTP supported by the Paypal endpoints. I have no idea if this is the case in Magento. But I am still receiving mails from Paypal that action is required. So I guess I am missing something.

Together with the hosting we set up a test file to check if the connection is ok:

Contents of paypaltest.php file:

```
<?php

$ch = curl_init('https://tlstest.paypal.com');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSLVERSION, 6);
$data = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);

echo $data;

?>
```

Result: PayPal_Connection_OK

I am running Magento 1.9.2.1. I would think this Magento version would include all settings to have PayPal work.

What I would like to know: 
- Do I needs some additional installation or version on my hosting?
- Do I need to change some settings in Magento?